# Flter expanded table with breeze

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, breeze

I am using in my project angular, breeze, WebApi, EF, SqlServer2008.
I have table Articles and table ArticleComments, So one article can have many articleComments records.

```
public class Article{

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ArticleImage> ImagesList { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ArticleComment
{
    public int ArticleCommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

in client I need to get full Article entity with comments, images and others linked entities, But comments need to be only for selected article record and where field "status" == 1.

I try to use such query

```
          var pred = breeze.Predicate.create('articleId', 'eq', id)
                  .and('comments', 'any', 'status', '==', 1);
          return EntityQuery.from("Articles")
            .where(pred)
            .expand('comments, imagesList...')
            .toType(entityNames.article)
            .using(manager).execute()
            .to$q(querySucceded, self._queryFailed);
```

this returns all comments for article , but does not filter expanded table ArticleComments by status field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support filtering when using ".Include(...)" which is what breeze's ".expand(...)" translates to on the server.  Similar questions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491332/breeze-filtering-expand-on-server-side) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629022/filtering-include-items-in-linq-and-entity-framework).

Your current query is saying:

> Give me the article with articleId==id as long as it has at least one
>   comment with status==1.  Include all of it's comments and images.

I believe what you want to express is:

> Give me the article with articleId==id.  Include comments whose status==1
>   and all of it's images.

I don't know of a way to express this in one query unless you create a dedicated controller action similar to what Jay describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492595/725866).

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
var pred = breeze.Predicate.create('articleId', 'eq', id);
return EntityQuery.from("Articles")
    .where(pred)
    .expand('comments, imagesList')
    .toType(entityNames.article)
    .using(manager)
    .execute()
    .to$q(
        function(result) {
            // detach all comments whose status!=1
            var commentType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityNames.articleComment),
                comments = manager.getEntities(commentType)
                     .filter(function(comment) { return comment.status !== 1; });
            comments.forEach(manager.detachEntity);
            querySucceded(result);
        },
        self._queryFailed);
```

Upside of this approach is it doesn't require server-side modifications.  Downside is it loads more comments than you need and forces you to detach them on the client afterwards.

A third approach would be to issue two queries:  one to load the article and it's imageList and a second query to load the comments whose articleId==id and status==1.  To do this you would need to have an action in your controller that returns an `IQueryable<ArticleComment>`.  Downside of this approach is you'd need to issue two http requests.  You could do these in parallel and with the advent of spdy this may not be such a big deal in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for expanded answer and your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy is right. This is a long standing EF pain. It's not made any better by the fact that OData doesn't support a way to filter the `expand`.

You can sort of do what you want on the server side with a projection. I played with this idea in the DocCode sample.

I added a new `CustomersAnd1998Orders` method to the [`NorthwindRepository`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindRepository.cs#L54) which is exposed to the client on the [`NorthwindController`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindRepository.cs#L54)

This is a fully queryable endpoint. It returns Customers and just those of their Orders that were ordered in 1998. The oddity is that it returns JSON typed as `CustomerDto` rather than `Customer`. You have to adjust for those with your client-side query ... as I'll explain below.

> I don't know why I have to do this. If I project into `Customer`, I get a runtime exception from EF.

Here's the `NorthwindRepositoryCustomersAnd1998Orders:

```
private class CustomerDto : Customer { } // EF requires a shadow class to make the LINQ query work
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersAnd1998Orders {
  get
  {
    return ForCurrentUser(Context.Customers)
    .Select(c => new CustomerDto {
      CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
      CompanyName =  c.CompanyName,
      ContactName =  c.ContactName,
      ContactTitle = c.ContactTitle,
      Address = c.Address,
      City = c.City,
      Region = c.Region,
      PostalCode = c.PostalCode,
      Country = c.Country,
      Phone =  c.Phone,
      Fax = c.Fax,
      RowVersion = c.RowVersion,

      Orders = c.Orders
                .Where(o =>  o.OrderDate != null && o.OrderDate.Value.Year == 1998)
                .ToList()
    });
  }
}
```

A bit tedious but if you need it, you need it.

The filter on 'Orders' selects for orders that were ordered in the year 1998 (this is old Northwind data). The `OrderDate` is `nullable<DateTime>` so we have to check for `null` and then pull the year out of the `Value`.

Notice that it projects with a `.Select` clause into `CustomerDto`,  a private, "do-nothing" subclass of `Customer`, so I'm technically returning an `IQueryable<CustomerDto>`. But it works.

The `NorthwindController.NorthwindRepositoryCustomersAnd1998Orders` betrays nothing:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersAnd1998Orders() {
  return _repository.CustomersAnd1998Orders;
}
```

Query on the Breeze client as you would the 'Customers' but without specifying the `.expand` clause; the server will take care of that.

There's one twist. See if you can detect it in [this test from DocCode](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/queryTests.js#L1425):

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('CustomersAnd1998Orders')
    .where('CompanyName', 'startsWith', 'C')
    .orderBy("CompanyName")
    .toType('Customer'); // Essential ... unless fix with a JsonResultsAdapter

verifyQuery(newEm, query,
    "Customers from 'CustomersAnd1998Orders' projection",
    showCompanyNamesAndOrderCounts,
    assertCustomersInCache,
    assertOrdersInCache,
    assertAllOrdersIn1998);
```

Yup. You have to cast the result to `Customer` because the type on the wire is "CustomerDto"

```
$type: "DocCode.DataAccess.NorthwindRepository+CustomerDto, DocCode.DataAccess.EF"
```

But at least you can filter (`.where()`) and sort (`orderBy()`) and page (`take()` and `skip()`) on the data tier.

Seems to me a small price to pay for this result?